# h264 syntax (P frames syntax details)

Tags: c++, video, video-streaming, h.264

I'm parsing h264 NAL Units. In my sequence - there are NAL Units with picture parameters set, sequence parameters set, I frames (they are also IDR) and P frames (I and P frames consits of single slice). (No B frames at all)

So I have the stream of NAL Units looks like:

```
[SPS] [PPS] [I(IDR)] [P] [P] [P] ... [P] [P] [SPS] [PPS] [I(IDR)] [P] [P] [P] ....
```

Each I frame in my stream is also IDR frame, so its frame_num is 0 (acording to h.264 standart).

Also each P frame has `frame_num` per unit greater than the previous frame.

But, I'm confused about `pic_order_cnt_lsb`.

What does `pic_order_cnt_lsb` represents?

In my sequence:

- if P frame has `frame_num==2` its
  `pic_order_cnt_lsb==4`
- if P frame has    `frame_num==3` its 
  `pic_order_cnt_lsb==6`
- if P frame has    `frame_num==4` its 
  `pic_order_cnt_lsb==8`
- etc... (in my situation `pic_order_cnt_lsb == 2*frame_num`)

And why there is such correlation between `frame_num` and `pic_order_cnt_lsb`?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have interlaced data. With interlaced data, one frame is composed of two fields. The other field of each frame will have the odd values for `pic_order_cnt_lsb`.

`pic_order_cnt_lsb` is just the least significant bits of a counter tracking the order of the pictures. If (as in typical interlaced data) you have two pictures per frame, then it'll increment by two for every change in the frame_num. If your stream was progressive instead of interlaced, the two would increment together.